# Determine a set of parametric equations for the xz plane.

Tags: calculus, vectors

How do you determine a set of parametric equations for the $xz$ plane?

Comment: Why bother with parametrics for a plane? You may just write $y=0$.

Comment: Thats just what the question asks i have no clue

Comment: @zz20s That seems to be the short, exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

The set of equations
$$
y=0\\
x=t\\
z=s
$$
for $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ works fine.

The question may be trying to connect 3-space geometry to linear algebra. The set of equations represent a system of 3 equations with two free variables in the $x$ and $z$ position.

Comment: what is the jacobian matrix of this xz plane ? is it defined?